# Is select N + 1 ever better than eager join?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

i am using nhibernate profiler and seeing  a few places where it is giving me a "Select n + 1" warning.

The obvious fix is to make some upfront eager joins but it got me thinking if in certain cases its actually simpler or faster to live with Select N + 1 compared to doing joins that may be load lots of data that you never actually use.

Comment: A third option is execution multiple queries that load parts of the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. In some cases, for example, all the root entities reference one or two instances of another entity. It might be faster to do 2 or 3 small selects instead of a denormalized one (i.e. with joins)

There is a way to make this convenient in almost all cases: `batch-size`. If you set this attribute in both the entities and the collections to your usual page size, you'll get a constant number of small selects (one per entity type).

Answer (score 1):

Select N+1 will become bigger and bigger problem once your application will have enough data in it.

Generally loading data is much cheaper then another trip to the data base. So if you can - you obviosly should avoid it.

As for loading additional data. If you are thinkg that you will load property values that are not going to be used you can use NHibernate 3.0 lazy loaded property feature.

So overall Select N+1 should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you know about another option

In your mappings add

```
<list name="MyItems" batch-size="10">
```

or

```
<bag name="MyItems" batch-size="10">
```

If you have 10 Items, you only need two queries instead of 11. For 20 items, you need
three instead of 21 and so on. This will cut out about 90 percent of your queries.