# Nhibernate performance considerations - need help compare eager loading versus batchsize decision

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, batch-file

based [on the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582214/is-select-n-1-ever-better-than-eager-join), it seems like batch size is the solution between having Select N + 1 queries and getting too much data with Eager Fetch calls.

What is the though process around determining my ideal batch size.

Should it be to try to get all in one query ? does increasing batch size start to slow down at some point?

I guess my question is why wouldn't i just always have a very large batch size to "catch" all select N + 1 situations?

Also, [in this article about nhibernate performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch), in the section (19.1.5. Using batch fetching) around nhibernate performance, this section talks about using batch fetching to optimize these queries (Cats --> Owners, Owners --> Children) but wouldn't an Eager Fetch be optimal in these cases if you know you will need to access that property of every item in your collection ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does increasing batch size start to
>   slow down at some point?

Maybe I am missing something here but `grabbing lots of data` in one trip is something you should try and avoid at all costs. Surely your paging strategy will first `reduce` the amount of rows you are returning. After you have worked out paging sizes then the batching can be fine tuned accordingly.

Personally if I have to set say a`batch-size` to say `100` then I would first address why I am returning all this data...

This of course is my opinion and without knowing your use case may not be correct.

Official Docs: [Improving performance by using batch fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-batch)

Comment: the previous person was doing no eager loading and all batching.  One page created 85 queries to the database (even with batching).  Eager fetching reduces this down to about 7 queries but i am trying to figure out if, from an overall performance point of view, i might be making the system slower given the larger dataset.

Comment: thanks for the link.  its great.  it actually brings up a few questions.  1) Why not ALWAYS use batch on everything to avoid Select N+1? is there any downside here?.  Also, do you have any thoughts on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584675/how-to-get-optimal-performance-with-recursive-self-joins-using-nhibernate as i can't find a pattern that works in nhibernate for recursive self joins

Comment: Not got an answer for that question. However have you thought about ditching nHibernate for this and using a CTE within a named `<sql-query ..>`

Comment: i have not thought of that.  Come to think about it how would you even do recursive joins in SQL directly??